# How to perform calculation on inserted row based on existind data in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Below is the initial table create query that produces the desired baseprice value - this is not a problem and works fine.

```
CREATE TABLE Tablebaseprice
SELECT    @PrevBasePrice := CASE
            WHEN @prevITS = st.its AND st.ppc IS NOT NULL THEN
              round(((1+st.ppc)*@prevBaseprice),3)
            ELSE 100
          END Baseprice,
          st.Date AS Date,
          @prevITS := st.its its,
          st.PPC
FROM      stemp st
ORDER BY  st.its, st.date;
```

But I'm stuck in figuring out how to calculate Baseprice when I insert new rows into the the existing table. Baseprice is calculated by taking the last or prior row's baseprice (prevBaseprice) for any given ITS and multiplying it by (1+ppc) - so I need to be able to pull the last instance of baseprice for any ITS in the existing table and multiply that by  PPC to generate the new baseprice for row I seek to insert.

Below is data from existing table:

```
baseprice   Date    its ppp
114.401 10/12/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM -0.013
105.993 10/19/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM -0.073
105.94  10/26/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM -0.001
106.025 11/02/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM 0.001
104.403 11/09/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM -0.015
102.92  11/16/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM -0.014
106.522 11/23/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM 0.035
```

But I want to insert the following:

```
11/30/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM -0.018
12/07/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM 0.01
```

but also calculate baseprice so new rows read :

```
104.605 11/30/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM   -0.018  /*(104.637=(1+ -0.018)*106.522*/
105.673 12/07/2012 12:00:00 AM  IBM 0.01
```